# How are flags marked helpful or not?

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags, helpful-flags

I'm reviewing and flagging different questions. Mostly flags are marked as helpful or not quickly and some flags are still pending from few weeks.

How does Stack Overflow decide which flag is helpful and which is not?